# Control key does funny things

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I switched from Windows to Linux Mint LMDE 64 with Cinnamon as window manager a few weeks ago on my Lenovo W510 notebook (but have good Linux knowledge from work about 10 years ago).
All is fine so far, but one thing bugs me.

Very often (not always) when I try to press a key combination including the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, something weird happens just after pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and before pressing an additional key.

Often when I use the Browser (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) or the programming editor (Lite IDE X)  just pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key starts the zoom function as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> would. That's most of the time when I try to call find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd>) or switch tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key several times solves the problem temporary then.

In Lite IDE I often find text fragments in opened source files where I'm sure that I did not put them there.
Most of the time the text fragments are code lines I copied/pasted sometimes earlier.
I have the suspicion, that here also some unintended keyboard shortcuts are executed that are the cause of this behavior.
So it seems it's not only the <kbd>+</kbd> key.

I don't use other applications very often yet, so no experience there.

I couldn't find anything about related known bugs.
Any ideas how to find the source of this behavior is very much appreciated.

Comment: After several months, this odd behavior stopped without an obvious reason.